# Asterisk dial plan priority

Tags: sip, asterisk, sip-server

I have an example asterisk dial plan below.It just the main (no extension or start) and it has 3 priorities.In the first priority of our extension, we’ll answer the call. In the second, we’ll play a sound file named hello-world.gsm, and in the third we’ll hang up the call

One example on the web seem to suggest the below format

```
[incoming]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

instead of

```
[incoming]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,2,Playback(hello-world)
exten => s,3,Hangup()
```

why is that? what exactly is a priority ? and what does 'n' signify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asterisk executes each [priority](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+priorities) in numerical order,
and like in BASIC, you can jump to those [Priorities](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+priorities) with `Goto`.

Since Asterisk 1.2 you have the ability to use the `n` [priority](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+priorities).

The `n` priority adds 1 to the previous Prioritiy.

That makes you more flexible, you could add a Line, without the need to care about the Priorities.

Another Benefit of the `n` [priority](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+priorities) is that you can use  the `n` Priority with optional Labels and jump to that Label, instead of messing arround with the priorities Counter.

```
[incoming]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n(Start),Background(hello-world)
exten => s,n,Goto(Start)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

See [GotoIf](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+GotoIf) for more examples.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this the following

```
exten => s,1,Answer() ;answer the call
same => n,playback(youfilename) ;understand that Asterisk will pick the best format to play
same => n,Hangup()
```

When using the same keyword you do not need to use the 's' in the dial plan.

Answer (score 2):

You can also save a bit of typing using the "same" construct on Asterisk 1.6+:

```
[incoming]
exten => s,1,Answer()
 same => n(Start),Background(hello-world)
 same => n,Goto(Start)
 same => n,Hangup()
```

... if you are doing large dialplans where you are doing a bit of cut-paste-tweak between different sections, such as IVRs, using "same" saves you from making an error with the extension number.

Further reading: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Contexts,+Extensions,+and+Priorities

Answer (score 0):

`n` stands for *Next Priority*.

In place of writing number in priority we can use "`n`" to represent the *next node*.

We can also use label with "`n`" e.g. `exten => s,n(dosomething)` if we are using `goto` or `gotoif` conditions in our `dialplan` then this labels help us to navigate to different "`n`" priority.